# Fetch data with react and componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to get some data from an api but for some reason it's not working.
Normally when i try to fetch data this way it's working fine

```
class App extends Component {
 constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
     items: []
   };
 }

 componentDidMount() {
   this.getData();
 }
 getData() {
   fetch(url)
     .then(results => results.json())
     .then(results => this.setState({ items: results }));
 }
 render() {
   const  {items} = this.state;
   return (
     <ul>
       {items.map(function(item, index) {
         return (
           <div>
             <li><h1>{console.log(item.title)}</h1></li>
           </div>
         );
       }
       )}
     </ul>
   );
 }
}
```

I got this error in the browser

```
TypeError: items.map is not a function
```

Comment: Are you sure `results` is an array? Looks like it's an object.

Comment: Please provide response data

Comment: items is either null or uniterable, please test with postman